# Ошибка при сборке и запуске проекта VCMI на Visual studio 2019

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, git, cmake

Ошибка при сборке проекта:

```
  Error copying file "AI/fuzzylite.dll" to "fuzzylite.dll".
D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): e
rror MSB3073: выход из команды "setlocal [D:\forked_projects\VCMI\build\client\vcmiclient.vcxproj]
D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): e
rror MSB3073: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noprofile -executionpolicy Bypass -file D:/for
ked_projects/VCMI/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/msbuild/applocal.ps1 -targetBinary D:/forked_projects/VCMI/build/bin/Debug
/VCMI_client.exe -installedDir D:/forked_projects/VCMI/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/bin -OutVariable out [D:\forke
d_projects\VCMI\build\client\vcmiclient.vcxproj]
D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): e
rror MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd [D:\forked_projects\VCMI\build\client\vcmiclient.vcxproj]
D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): e
rror MSB3073: :cmEnd [D:\forked_projects\VCMI\build\client\vcmiclient.vcxproj]
D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): e
rror MSB3073: endlocal & call :cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% & goto :cmDone [D:\forked_projects\VCMI\build\client\vcmiclien
t.vcxproj]
D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): e
rror MSB3073: :cmErrorLevel [D:\forked_projects\VCMI\build\client\vcmiclient.vcxproj]
D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): e
rror MSB3073: exit /b %1 [D:\forked_projects\VCMI\build\client\vcmiclient.vcxproj]
D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): e
rror MSB3073: :cmDone [D:\forked_projects\VCMI\build\client\vcmiclient.vcxproj]
D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): e
rror MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :VCEnd [D:\forked_projects\VCMI\build\client\vcmiclient.vcxproj]
D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): e
rror MSB3073: setlocal [D:\forked_projects\VCMI\build\client\vcmiclient.vcxproj]
D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): e
rror MSB3073: cd D:\forked_projects\VCMI\build\bin\Debug [D:\forked_projects\VCMI\build\client\vcmiclient.vcxproj]
D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): e
rror MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd [D:\forked_projects\VCMI\build\client\vcmiclient.vcxproj]
D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): e
rror MSB3073: D: [D:\forked_projects\VCMI\build\client\vcmiclient.vcxproj]
D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): e
rror MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd [D:\forked_projects\VCMI\build\client\vcmiclient.vcxproj]
D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): e
rror MSB3073: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E copy AI/fuzzylite.dll fuzzylite.dll [D:\forked_projects\VCMI\bu
ild\client\vcmiclient.vcxproj]
D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): e
rror MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd [D:\forked_projects\VCMI\build\client\vcmiclient.vcxproj]
D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): e
rror MSB3073: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E copy AI/tbb.dll tbb.dll [D:\forked_projects\VCMI\build\client\v
cmiclient.vcxproj]
D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): e
rror MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd [D:\forked_projects\VCMI\build\client\vcmiclient.vcxproj]
D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): e
rror MSB3073: :cmEnd [D:\forked_projects\VCMI\build\client\vcmiclient.vcxproj]
D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): e
rror MSB3073: endlocal & call :cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% & goto :cmDone [D:\forked_projects\VCMI\build\client\vcmiclien
t.vcxproj]
D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): e
rror MSB3073: :cmErrorLevel [D:\forked_projects\VCMI\build\client\vcmiclient.vcxproj]
D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): e
rror MSB3073: exit /b %1 [D:\forked_projects\VCMI\build\client\vcmiclient.vcxproj]
D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): e
rror MSB3073: :cmDone [D:\forked_projects\VCMI\build\client\vcmiclient.vcxproj]
D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): e
rror MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :VCEnd [D:\forked_projects\VCMI\build\client\vcmiclient.vcxproj]
D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): e
rror MSB3073: :VCEnd" с кодом 1. [D:\forked_projects\VCMI\build\client\vcmiclient.vcxproj]
  Automatic MOC for target vcmieditor
  vcmieditor.vcxproj -> D:\forked_projects\VCMI\build\bin\Debug\VCMI_mapeditor.exe
  Automatic MOC for target vcmilauncher
  vcmilauncher.vcxproj -> D:\forked_projects\VCMI\build\bin\Debug\VCMI_launcher.exe

D:\forked_projects\VCMI\build>
```

Ошибка запуске готового vcml.sln :

```
|Ошибка|MSB3073|выход из команды setlocal
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noprofile -executionpolicy Bypass -file D:/forked_projects/VCMI/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/msbuild/applocal.ps1 -targetBinary D:/forked_projects/VCMI/build/bin/Debug/VCMI_client.exe -installedDir D:/forked_projects/VCMI/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/bin -OutVariable out
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
:cmEnd
endlocal & call :cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% & goto :cmDone
:cmErrorLevel
exit /b %1
:cmDone
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :VCEnd
setlocal
cd D:\forked_projects\VCMI\build\bin\Debug
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
D:
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe -E copy AI/fuzzylite.dll fuzzylite.dll
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe -E copy AI/tbb.dll tbb.dll
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
:cmEnd
endlocal & call :cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% & goto :cmDone
:cmErrorLevel
exit /b %1
:cmDone
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :VCEnd
:VCEnd с кодом 1.|VCMI_client|D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 2019\Community\Msbuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets|155||
```

С чем может быть связана эта ошибка?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена добавлением ручками в исходный каталог файлов fuzzylite.dll и tdd.dll из пакета vcpkg.